# What function does the "to" have below this context?

Tags: grammar

> The company announced it was reneging on a longstanding commitment **to** abide by the strict nuclear regulations."

What does the "to" means? Does it mean the company needs to renege the commitment so they can be abled to abide the regulations? Or it means that the commitment is about to abide the regulation?

Answer (score 1):

You're right.   There's an ambiguity.   From that position, the "to" could attach to either "commitment" or "reneging".

In the absence of further context, the more likely modificand is "commitment".   It's closer.   It's sensible.   In the context of [this article](http://archive.boston.com/bostonglobe/editorial_opinion/editorials/articles/2011/04/24/vermont_yankee_plants_owner_must_honor_its_own_promises/), that *is* the intended meaning.   For example, it's the one that agrees with the statement "Either Entergy never really intended to live by those commitments, or it simply didn’t foresee what would happen next."

However, that same structure -- indeed, that same sentence -- might well have that other interpretation in another context.   The "to" *could* mark the purpose of reneging rather than the nature of the commitment.   Both parsings are grammatically sound.

Because of this ambiguity, it is more likely that the author would have placed the infinitive phrase in an introductory position if it were intended to attach to the main verb of the clause.  As it stands, there is more than enough context in that article to justify exactly one interpretation of this sentence.

Comment: Bingo. It could mean "***in order to** abide by...*" The sentence is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

The commitment was to abide by the strict nuclear regulations.  That is, the company originally said, "We will abide by these nuclear regulations."  That's the commitment.  Then the company said, "We have decided not to do that any more."  That's the reneging.

To break the sentence down, look at it this way:

**The company announced it was** (what was it doing?)
**reneging** (what were they reneging on?)
**on a longstanding commitment** (what was the commitment to?)
**to abide by the strict nuclear regulations**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if I change this sentence into "To abide by the strict nuclear regulations, the company announced it was reneging on a longstanding commitment", Althouth it sounds weird, the meaning will be differernt, isn't it? If we only focus on the grammar, is the modified sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: @asuo99 Yes, your new sentence is grammatically correct but means something different from the original sentence.

Answer (score 0):

When the verb *commit* means:

> obligate, bind or to pledge or assign to some particular course or use

it can be followed by a *to infintive*:

> a contract ***committing*** the company ***to** complete* the project on time ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commit))

As a noun, ***[commitment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commitment)*** preserves this possibility to be followed by a to infinitive:

> a ***commitment to** improve* conditions at the prison

In your sentence, *to abide by the strict nuclear regulations* is an infinitive non-finite clause playing the role of an adjective: it modifies the noun *commitment*, answering the question *"which commitment?"*